# Nginx ProxyPassReverse setup

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have a task to connect a jitsi server with my existing domain. The jitsi server should be running in a subpath like `https://dev.example.com/video`.

I have installed jitsi in aws with hostname `https://dev.example.com`.

For this to work I have to set up an nginx block that will remove `/video` while sending a request to the jitsi server and add `/video` on the responses.

The plan was to add an upstream in my nginx as follows.

```
upstream jitsi {
    server 10.10.10.20:443;
}

location /video/ {
  rewrite ^/video/(.*) /$1  break; 
  proxy_pass https://jitsi/$uri$is_args$args; 
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect https://dev.example.com/ https://dev.example.com/video/;
}
```

The rewrite will strip away the `/video` and the rest is supposed to add it on the response. But when loading the page, browser is showing 404 for some of the internal links.

eg:

```
https://dev.example.com/libs/do_external_connect.min.js?v=1
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 124ms]

https://dev.example.com/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js?v=4466
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 123ms]

https://dev.example.com/libs/app.bundle.min.js?v=4466
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 123ms]

https://dev.example.com/static/pwa/registrator.js
```

I could clearly see that the last part which is supposed to add `/video` into the URL is not working correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance